# ASP.Net MVC Hidden field on form postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, hidden-field

I have a controller and a strongly-typed view in my solution.  In the view I have a hidden field which initially blank.  I have a form in the view which the user can click a "Submit" button to submit the form to the controller action.  Within the controller action I am modifying a value inside the model and then redisplaying the same form (that was previously posted) with the modified model.  On the View, I am writing the value of the model field inside of the HTML hidden field tag so it will be visible to client-side javascript.  The problem I am having is that in the javascript, the value of the hidden field on the posted back form is blank, even though the server-side value of the hidden field is being set correctly after post-back.  What I need is for the client-side javascipt to be able to see the modified value of the hidden field.  What do I need to do to make this happen?

```
<HttpPost()> _
Function Index(ByVal model As MaxDocument, formcollection As FormCollection) As ActionResult
  Dim sCriteria As String = ""
  Dim nKeyIndex As Integer = 0
  Dim nFieldIndex As Integer = -1
  Dim sFieldValue As String = ""
  Dim vrl As List(Of MaxServerLib.ValidationResult) = Nothing

  Try
    model.GetFileCabinetFieldList()
    For nFieldIndex = 0 To (model.IndexFieldCount - 1)
      sFieldValue = ""
      If nFieldIndex > 0 Then
        sCriteria += "~"
      End If
      Dim fcf As MaxServerLib.FileCabinetField = model.criterionAtIndex(nFieldIndex)
        ' Get the field value corresponding to this field
        For Each oKey As Object In FormCollection.AllKeys
          If oKey.ToString = fcf.sFieldName Then
            sFieldValue = FormCollection(oKey.ToString)
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        sCriteria += sFieldValue
      Next
      If sCriteria = "" Then sCriteria = "[BlankIndex]"

      ' First thing we do is to perform valiation of the criteria
      model.ValidateFieldValues(sCriteria)
      If Not model.AllFieldValuesValid() Then
        ' Handle case where one or more field values are invalid.
        ' In this case we want to redisplay the form but show an error message listing the invalid fields

        ' Populate the message to be displayed to the user
        model.FormatErrorMessage()
        ' test code start
        ModelState.Clear()
        ' test cod end
        ' Return RedirectToAction("Index", New With {.sMaxUrl = model.MaxUrl, .sDataSource = model.DataSource, .sSessionTicket = model.SessionTicket, .dtLastCall = model.LastCall, .sFileCabinetid = model.FileCabinetId, .sFileCabinetName = model.FileCabinetName, .sShowMsg = MaxServerLib.EscapeString(model.ShowMsg)})
        Return View(model)
      Else
        ' All field values are valid, now attempt to add the document
        If model.ExportDocument() Then
          ' Document export was successful
          System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
        Else
          ' Document export failed for some reason
          ModelState.AddModelError("", model.LastError)
          Return View(model)
        End If
      End If

      ' Return RedirectToAction("Index", "SearchResults", New With {.sMaxUrl = model.MaxUrl, .sDataSource = model.DataSource, .sSessionTicket = model.SessionTicket, .dtLastCall = model.LastCall, .sFileCabinetId = model.FileCabinetId, .sFileCabinetName = model.FileCabinetName, .sSearchCriteria = sSearchCriteria})
    Catch ex As Exception
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
    End Try
  'End If

  ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  Return View(model)

End Function
```

Comment: show the view markup related to hidden field

Comment: Almost impossible to help without seeing some markup, Brian.

Comment: View markup to hidden field is: @<input type="hidden" id="hdnShowMsg" name="hdnShowMsg" value="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.ShowMsg)" />

Comment: In the above, I can place a break-point and see that the hidden field is set correctly from the server-side, and yet the client-side java-script does not read the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting back the same form, then most likely it is pulling the original values from the model state while it is binding up.

Call ModelState.Clear() before returning the form to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have already tried clearing the modelstate and it did not fix the issue.  This issue is apparently related to when the javascript code in the view gets executed.  I had assumed that the javascript would only be executed after the server-side code had completed but perhaps this is not true if the server-side code sets the hidden field correctly but the client-side code does not see the updated value.

Comment: when the partial is returned, how do you get it back into your page?  can you edit your question and show the code there?

Comment: I pass the modified model to the view. See edited question for the controller code that handles the post.